# Java авторизация в ssh

Tags: java, ssh

Как в java приложении можно авторизоваться в ssh ?

Comment: @Родион Преображенский, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Java secure channel - одна из лучших джава библиотек для работы с ssh.

**Обновление**

Что Вы подразумеваете под большим числом? 10? 100? 1000? На самом деле количество соединений ограничено возможностями Вашей ОС и аппаратуры. Не забудьте, что в ssh используется шифрование и при большом количестве соединений нагрузка на процессор тоже будет значительной.

Comment: Мне нужно работать одновременно с большим числом ssh коннектов,
подойдет ли эта библиотека для этого?

Comment: коннектов может быть до 1000.
при примерно 30-50 коннектов в некоторых потоках появляются ошибки
Too many authentication failures for user